# What Trainer level is necessary to complete the last tournament?

Tags: magikarp-jump

In Magikarp Jump, you can get higher max level when you level up.

What Magikarp level is needed to beat the last tournament, and so what trainer level do you need to beat that tournament?

Comment: Last stage of luxury league needs 17.4M JP to guarantee a win. I'll update that w/ a magikarp level once I get a new karp...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Original - for version 1.02:

Per [Serebii](https://serebii.net/magikarpjump/leagues/expertleague3.shtml), the highest JP you will encounter in an opponent is 58.1M JP (final karp in Expert League 3).  This is achievable with a level **60** Magikarp (see [list of MagiKarp JP/Level](https://serebii.net/magikarpjump/raisingmagikarp.shtml)) to win without a support boost.

A level **59** Magikarp (max JP 52k) could win with a 25% support boost, but not with a 5%.

### Edit for 1.1.0 Update (adding Heal League):

The new maximum for the Heal League is  135,188,472, which is apparently nearly identical to the Level **66** maximum of 135,188,474, according to [Serebii](https://serebii.net/magikarpjump/raisingmagikarp.shtml).  I'm not sure how accurate the numbers are at the bottom (you can only see "135M") so it's unclear how they know the precise values, and it's possible you'll need to actually be level 67.  It could be beaten at +25% at the level 65 maximum.

The new maximum for Expert League 3 is 430,524,767, slightly lower than the Level **73** maximum (which is the new overall maximum).  It could be beaten at +25% at the level 72 maximum.

Comment: And therefore the trainer level is...50 (or 49), right? Well, I guess it could be even lower thanks to the possibility of Macho Karp increasing your Magikarp's max level despite a lower trainer level.

Comment: Yep.  (That's why they list 61 as maximum level, though it's really 60 without macho karp.  Though I've seen arguments that macho karp doesn't actually surpass 60, so not sure if this is calculated or observed maximums.)

Comment: When you hit max level, Macho Karp event/Ghost TV Girl don't do anything.

Comment: Also, this answer is outdated now with the heal league :o

Comment: @KevinL Updated.  I will continue to update as changes occur.

Comment: Well since you so generously volunteered to update as changes occur... (it happened like two weeks ago btw)